# ¿Cómo implementar una interfaz de usuario correctamente en android?

Tags: android, xml, design

Mi pregunta va dirigida a todos los designers y developers.

Conforme trato de realizar layouts un poco mas elaboradas me encuentro con problemas para mantener el aspecto en todos los dispositivos(Esto debido a mi poca experiencia).

Justo ahora estoy tratando de construir esta misma vista en android:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y casi lo logro:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, al momento de bajar la palabra "cyan" obtengo este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi xml, después de agregar un alignBottom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_container_color"
    style="@style/color_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="60">

    <TextView
        android:fontFamily="@font/msyi"
        android:id="@+id/tv_number"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:text="500"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="50dp" />

    <TextView
        android:fontFamily="@font/msyi"
        android:id="@+id/tv_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/tv_number"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/tv_number"
        android:layout_below="@id/tv_number"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="standar"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:fontFamily="@font/msyi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:text="cyan"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginHorizontal="50dp">
    <TextView
        android:fontFamily="@font/msyi"
        android:id="@+id/tv_hex"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hex: 34BCD4"
        android:textSize="25dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:fontFamily="@font/msyi"
        android:id="@+id/tv_rgb"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="rgb: 52 188 212"
        android:textSize="25dp"/>

</LinearLayout>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dp">

    <TextView
        android:fontFamily="@font/msyi"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Esto es un horizontal scroll view"
        android:textSize="25dp">

    </TextView>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

No es la primera vez que me pasa, en otras ocasiones he resuelto la misma situación, sin embargo, han sido resultados poco prácticos...

Si tienen alguna documentación estaría de maravilla.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí el *problema* que yo veo es que no **anulas** en este caso la **altura** `android:layout_height="0dp"` a la hora de marcar la propiedad `android:layout_weight=""`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rl_container_color"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="70">

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/msyi"
            android:id="@+id/tv_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:text="500"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="50dp" />

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/msyi"
            android:id="@+id/tv_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/tv_number"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/tv_number"
            android:layout_below="@id/tv_number"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="standar"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/msyi"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:text="cyan"
            android:textSize="50dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="50dp">
        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/msyi"
            android:id="@+id/tv_hex"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hex: 34BCD4"
            android:textSize="25dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/msyi"
            android:id="@+id/tv_rgb"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="rgb: 52 188 212"
            android:textSize="25dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp">

        <TextView
            android:fontFamily="@font/msyi"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Esto es un horizontal scroll view"
            android:textSize="25dp">

        </TextView>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Resultado:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]